# 403 Forbidden error when accessing linkedin login api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API in my sample application . when i tried to log in in to linked in. It is giving me an

> 403 forbidden error

It was working with these Url's:

```
tokenEndpoint="https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken"
authEndpoint="https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize"
```

Comment: In which JS or Python ?

Comment: Can you share request that you are trying to pass? These are just API endpoints